# Unable to initialize @StateObject ViewModel in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

I am trying to inject the managedObjectContext in ViewModel and for some weird reason it is throwing a weird error.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @StateObject var addBudgetVM: AddBudgetViewModel
    
    init() {
        // THIS LINE CAUSES ISSUES 
        addBudgetVM = AddBudgetViewModel(context: viewContext)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
       // some code here
    }
    
}

Cannot assign to property: 'addBudgetVM' is a get-only property
```

Here is the implementation of AddBudgetViewModel

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class AddBudgetViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var name: String = ""
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext
    
    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.context = context
    }
    
    func save() {
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635914/initialize-stateobject-with-a-parameter-in-swiftui

Comment: @workingdog But I need to pass managedObjectContext

Comment: You could make the context optional on your view model and set it on `onAppear`

Comment: Or inject the view model into the view

Comment: I agree with @JoakimDanielson. You should inject the view model from the superview

Comment: Can you explain in terms of code?

Comment: If I inject the ViewModel into the View it will create an instance of the VM for each time the View is rendered.

Comment: If you inject the view model then a new view model instance will be created if the superview is re-rendered (The one that injected the view model), but not if things change with the view that is using the view model.

Comment: This is SwiftUI you shouldn’t be using view model objects you should instead be using structs and value semantics. Also ObservableObject and @Published are part of the Combine framework but you don’t have a Combine pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I find the best approach is to inject the view model from the superview.  This nicely separates the view, which consumes the view model, from the creation of the view model.  It improves testability as it makes it easy to inject a mock view model.

Something like:

```
struct ParentView: View {
      @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext

      var body: some View {
          //...
          AddBudgetView(viewModel: AddBudgetViewModel(context: viewContext))
          //...
      }
}


struct AddBudgetView: View {

      viewModel: AddBudgetViewModel 

      var body: some View {
          // ...
      }
}

class AddBudgetViewModel: ObservableObject {

    private (set) var context: NSManagedObjectContext

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    
        self.context = context
    }

   func save() {
    
   }
}
```

I probably wouldn't even have Core Data code in the view model. I would put all of that in a main model and pass the main model instance to the view model initialiser instead of the managed object context.  The view model can then call methods on the main model to create and save items.  This way your view model is isolated from the storage implementation detail and you could make changes to your store, such as replacing Core Data, without having to touch view models all over the place.