# Need data to initialize a StateObject

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a StateObject which I need to initialize with properties from Settings:

```
@State private var settingsStore = SettingsStore()
@StateObject var matrix = Matrix(d: settingsStore.d)
```

How do I do this? I can't make it a computed property because it's a state object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635914/initialize-stateobject-with-a-parameter-in-swiftui

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe you are trying to use these properties inside a `View`.

To solve your problem, you can simply split your code in two different views, where in the first one you define the `SettingsStore` instance, then you use it to initialise the `Matrix` instance of the second view.

Like this:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State private var settingsStore = SettingsStore()
    
    var body: some View {
        SubView(settingsStore: $settingsStore, matrix: Matrix(d: settingsStore.d))
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @Binding var settingsStore: SettingsStore
    @StateObject var matrix: Matrix
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(matrix.d)
    }

}
```