# Do something as soon as UIViewRepresentable is instantiated

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable, swift-structs

This seems like a straightforward question, but I have not been able to find any solutions in the Swift docs. When I was programming in Kotlin, it was common to use the `init()` method of a class to perform some work in order to get the class set up and ready for use.

Now I am creating a `UIViewRepresentable` and would like to do something as soon as this struct is initialized. It seems that the `init()` method for structs is only concerned with member initialization.

For example, the `.onAppear` method for a `View` provides this functionality as follows:

```
struct MapView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = MapViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region,
            interactionModes: .all,
            showsUserLocation: true)
        .onAppear { 
            // this will occur as soon as the View appears
            viewModel.safeCreateLocationManager()
            
        }
    }
}
```

But now when defining a `UIViewRepresentable` struct I am wishing to do the same:

```
struct OverlayMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = MapViewModel()
    
    // immediately do the following: 
    viewModel.safeCreateLocationManager()

    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        ...
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<OverlayMapView>) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but would be not correct (so I will not tell even how), instead use it

```
struct OverlayMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = MapViewModel()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
       viewModel.safeCreateLocationManager()    // << here !!

       // view creation is next ...
```

*the `makeUIView` is called after `init` and before `onAppear`

Comment: Thanks for this, I agree this seems like a good approach but out of curiosity can you please link to the incorrect method? I am still new to Swift and curious about how the language works.

Comment: In init, create view model, call a method, then initialise state object with that model. Like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62636048/12299030. But pay attention (!) SwiftUI view init can be called many, many times - it is a value-type and creation/re-creation in general not controlled by us.