# In SwiftUI, should bindings go in the ViewModel?

Tags: ios, swiftui, mvvm

I might be misunderstanding a couple of key concepts, but not seeing how to properly handle view bindings and retain proper MVVM structure with SwiftUI.

Let's take this example of two fields that affect the text above them:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var firstName =  "John"
    @State var lastName = "Smith"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("first name: \(firstName)")
            Text("last name: \(lastName)")

            ChangeMeView(firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName)
        }

    }

}

struct ChangeMeView: View {
    @Binding var firstName: String
    @Binding var lastName: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("first name", text: $firstName)
            TextField("last name", text: $lastName)
        }
    }

}
```

Works as expected. However, if I wanted to follow MVVM, wouldn't I need to move (firstName, lastName) to a ViewModel object within that view?
[image]

That means that the view starts looking like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var firstName =  "John"
    @State var lastName = "Smith"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("first name: \(firstName)")
            Text("last name: \(lastName)")

            ChangeMeView(firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName)
        }

    }

}

struct ChangeMeView: View {
//    @Binding var firstName: String
//    @Binding var lastName: String

    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    init(firstName: Binding<String>, lastName: Binding<String>) {
        //from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635914/initialize-stateobject-with-a-parameter-in-swiftui#62636048
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName))
    }


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("first name", text: viewModel.firstName)
            TextField("last name", text: viewModel.lastName)
        }
    }

}


class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var firstName: Binding<String>
    var lastName: Binding<String>

    init(firstName: Binding<String>, lastName: Binding<String>) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

This works but feels to me like it might be hacky. Is there another smarter way to pass data (like bindings) to a view while retaining MVVM?

Here's an example where I try using @Published. While it runs, the changes don't update the text:

```
struct ContentView: View {
     var firstName =  "John"
     var lastName = "Smith"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("first name: \(firstName)")
            Text("last name: \(lastName)")

            ChangeMeView(viewModel: ViewModel(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName))
        }

    }

}

struct ChangeMeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        //apple approved strategy from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635914/initialize-stateobject-with-a-parameter-in-swiftui#62636048
//        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName))
    }


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("first name", text: $viewModel.firstName)
            TextField("last name", text: $viewModel.lastName)
        }
    }

}


class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var firstName: String
    @Published var lastName: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

Comment: No Binding is only for SwiftUI views

Comment: You would remove the `@State` and `@Binding` properties. Your view model should be an an `ObservableObject` with `@Published` properties.  You pass an instance of your view model to your view's initialiser

Comment: @Paulw11 - I updated the last example with your suggestions. Not quite getting that to work.

Comment: In your updated example you don't have a shared, published property between your `ContentView` and your `ChangeMeView`.  You could share the view model instance or you can make things more complicated and implement full MVVM - Where you have a model and two view models and the view models are responsible for updating and exposing changes from the model.  Compare what you have with the diagram in your question; You have a view model, but no model. SwiftUI tends to work best when you really decompose your views, but creating a separate view model for each view can be overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the *model* part of MVVM.  In a simple example, as you have here, you probably don't need full MVVM - You can just share a *view model* between your two views.

However, here is how you can use a model and a view model. The model and view model classes first:

The model just declares two `@Published` properties and is an `@ObservableObject`

**Model**

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var firstName: String = ""
    @Published var lastName: String = ""
    
}
```

The `ContentViewModel` is initialised with the `Model` instance and simply exposes the two properties of the model via computed properties.

**ContentViewModel**

```
class ContentViewModel {
    
    let model: Model
    
    var firstName:String {
        return model.firstName
    }
    var lastName:String {
        return model.lastName
    }
    
    init(model: Model) {
        self.model = model
    }
    
}
```

`ChangeMeViewModel` is a little more complex - It needs to both expose the current values from the `Model` but also update the values in the `Model` when the values are set in the `ChangeMeViewModel`.  To make this happen we use a custom `Binding`. The `get` methods are much the same as the `ContentViewModel` - They just accesses the properties from the `Model` instance.  The `set` method takes the new value that has been assigned to the `Binding` and updates the properties in the `Model`

**ChangeMeViewModel**

```
class ChangeMeViewModel {
    
    let model: Model
    
    var firstName: Binding<String>
    var lastName: Binding<String>
    
    init(model: Model) {
        self.model = model
        self.firstName = Binding(
            get: {
                return model.firstName
            },
            set: { newValue in
                model.firstName = newValue
            }
        )
        
        self.lastName = Binding(
            get: {
                return model.lastName
            },
            set: { newValue in
                model.lastName = newValue
            }
        )
    }
    
}
```

Finally we need to create the `Model` in the `App` file and use it with the view models in the view hierarchy:

**App**

```
@main
struct MVVMApp: App {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(viewModel: ContentViewModel(model: model))
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let viewModel: ContentViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("first name: \(self.viewModel.firstName)")
            Text("last name: \(self.viewModel.lastName)")
            
            ChangeMeView(viewModel:ChangeMeViewModel(model:self.viewModel.model))
        }
    }
}
```

**ChangeMeView**

```
struct ChangeMeView: View {
    
    let viewModel: ChangeMeViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("first name", text: self.viewModel.firstName)
            TextField("last name", text: self.viewModel.lastName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write it up! The example I posted was meant to show where I was lost. The actual view I'm working on has a decent list of bindings, and I was trying to see if I could encapsulate that better within a view model. Leveraging getters and setters here make a ton of sense, and might help remove some of the clutter

Comment: Interesting approach. This certainly eliminates a couple of potential subtle issues which may arise when using "two way bindings" while striving implementing the MVVM pattern, since with your approach, the Model can gain full control over the "setter" and whether and how the value will change (actually in one RunLoop cycle), which the view will render. One caveat though is, that there is an additional layer (the class `ChangeMeViewModel `) required. Folks who strive for simplicity or folks who yet need to discover those subtle pitfalls with two-way bindings may not like it (unfortunately).

Comment: Can you please provide/update this to use new Observation framework which uses "Bindable" instead of binding?